# jQuery method - hand over variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a plugin, and I got the basic setup from the [jQuery plugin authoring tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( items ) { 
        /* do stuff */
    },
    reset : function( name ) {
        // here I need the var items from init
    }
  };

  $.fn.myplugin = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

How can I get in the method `reset` the variable `items` from `init`?

Thanks and regards, alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store them in the smallest common scope, e.g. the `methods` object:

```
  var methods = {
    init : function( items ) { 
        /* do stuff */
        methods.myData = 15;
    },
    reset : function( name ) {
        // here I need the var items from init
        alert(methods.myData * 2); // alerts 30
    }
  };
```